# ASP.NET ReportViewer Control Fonts to Century Gothic

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

We are using ASP.NET ReportViewer Control to render rdl files. In the rdl files we have set the font to “Century Gothic” and in preview mode it renders the fonts nicely. However – when it gets rendered on browser we see the fonts defaulted to “Times New Roman”.

I tried couple of things without success:
1.  Setting the font family of the page ()
2.  Setting the FontNames of the ReportViewer control

Please let me know how we can render the fonts to Century Gothic.

One more thing is I don't see Century Gothic in the list of available fonts in the HTML Editor inside Visual Studio 2010. Do I need to add them somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The target client system where the reports were browsed, didn't had the font installed. Once we installed the fonts, the reports started coming in the font.